# How to use LIKE and NOT LIKE together in a SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

I have this a SQL Server table `Users` with a column `codename` with a lot of records, example:

```
...
[LP]Luis
JoseLuis
[LP]Pedroso
Luis
PedroLuis
[LP]Maria
CarlosJose
MariaJose
[LP]Carlos
Pedro
...
```

I need to make a query for a search form that ignore all `codename`s that contain `[LP]`

I wrote and run the following query:

```
SELECT TOP (15)* 
FROM [Users] 
WHERE [codename] LIKE '%Luis%'
AND [codename] NOT LIKE '%[LP]%'
```

This query doesn't return anything.

I want to get (In this example) the records:

```
Luis
PedroLuis
JoseLuis
```

If I query:

```
SELECT TOP (15) * 
FROM [Users] 
WHERE [codename] LIKE '%Luis%'
```

I get:

```
[LP]Luis
JoseLuis
Luis
PedroLuis
```

and if I add to the query:

```
AND [codename] NOT LIKE '%[LP]%'
```

I get nothing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

All of the strings have either an `L` or `P`, which is what `%[LP]%` looks for.

One way is to escape the pattern:

```
SELECT TOP (15) * 
FROM [Users] 
WHERE [codename] LIKE '%Luis%' AND
      [codename] NOT LIKE '%/[LP/]%' escape '/';
```

Comment: Upvoted. You could also escape `[` by enclosing it in `[]`, i.e. `codename NOT LIKE '%[[]LP]%'`.

Comment: Ok, I did not know that [] is used as wildcards, that was my mistake.. Both solutions work correctly. I'll use the @Felix-Pamittan's solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, When we use starting % wildcard in like query at that time index for that column will be used or not? If not how to overcome that issue?

Comment: @RGS . . . A standard index on a string column is used for `LIKE` only when the pattern does not begin with a wildcard.